# MVC DropDown from DataBase

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
public class DropDown
{

    public string[] SelectedItems { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }

}
```

Am trying to get a DropDown in MVC from DB with above structure.

From DataBase I got the Text and value field and having in `IEnumerable<T>` where T has 2 properties id and text.

What is the best way convert ienumerable id to array of string and assign id, text to `SelectedListItem` ?

I thought of looping through the ienumerable and forming the DropDown, but thought there will be better ways.

## update

For example :

```
In DB i have student table with
 ID,
 Name,
 Class,
 Section
```

And i got id and Name in  `ienumerable<student>` . From there i need to convert into a `DropDown`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951524/mvc-and-entity-framework-select-list/17953161#17953161

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<Student> studentList = GetStudentList();
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> dropdownItems = new MultiSelectList(studentList, "ID", "Name",selectedValues);

DropDown dropDown = new DropDown { Items = dropdownItems  };
```

If you want to create a listbox you can do it with HTML helpers like this:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(item => item.SelectedStudents, new MultiSelectList(Model.StudentList, "ID", "Name",selectedValues))
```

Comment: i need to foreach from Ienumerable<T> to dropdown class !

Comment: i already have data for dropdown in Ienumerable<T> i need to convert to the class of DropDown type with array of string and SelectList item

Comment: @user2067567 I don't understand. What do you have in your DB exactly?

Comment: i can get new selectlist item but am not sure how to get selectedvalues as am having a listbox

Comment: @user2067567 Then you should use MultiSelectList class. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure why you are trying to create your own DropDown class, why not use the built-in MVC HTML Helper?

If you have an IEnumerable that you want to turn into a SelectList which will be consumed by the helper, something like this would work:

```
var selectListItems = from t in items
select new SelectListItem{
     Text = t.Text,
     Value = t.Id
}.ToList();
```

Then fire it over to your view, you could ideally use a viewmodel, but the ViewBag works too:

```
ViewBag.SelectListItems = selectListItems;
```

Finally, have your HTML Helper build your drop down for you in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectListItems")
```

Comment: Am trying to send without using viewbag !

Answer (score 0):

It looks like maybe you want multiple dropdowns for every array position in selectedItems? If so, I just had this problem last week. I called a foreach inside [Html.DropDownListFor(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

```
<%    for(int i = 0; i < Model.SelectedItems.length; i++) %>
    <%: Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedItems[i], Model.Items %>
```