# Dropdown list with items from database in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postgresql, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have this 2 models

```
  public class FileType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }



public class Genre
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("FileType")]
        public int FileTypeID { get; set; }
    }
```

And tables with data in PostgreSQL database for these models, i want to create 2 dropdownlists in view with Name for filetype and name for genre.I want to create that 2 ddl in this upload view

```
 public class FileUploadViewModel
    {
        public List<FileModel> Files { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Extension { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; }
        public string FilePath { get; set; }
        public string PublishedOn { get; set; }
        public int DownloadCounter { get; set; }
     
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MVC DropDown from DataBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211872/mvc-dropdown-from-database)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a dropdown list for `FileTypeID`, you could try this:

```
(...)
public class Genre
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("FileType")]
        public FileType FileTypeID { get; set; }
    }

public enum FileType
{
Item1,
Item2,
Item3,
Item4
}
```

Then, in your view:

```
@model YourNameSpace.Models.Genre

@{
    ViewData["Title"] ="xyz";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FileTypeID, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(FileType))), "Select FileType", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

You will then see a dropdown list with the four selectable items `item1`-`item4` and a default placeholder stating "Select FileType".

Comment: i want to bind data from database not from enum

Comment: Well you can't communicate with the database via the views unless you use to the model to do exactly that. The model is your gateway to the database. At some point, the model needs to be flush with the db. I think the only question is: do go code-first or do you go db first. I suggest carving out the model first and then use EF migration to create your database. Set your db parameters in ConfigureServices in the startup file before migration and it should all be flush. Does this make sense so far?

Comment: I understand you and i have models and tables in db,i fill tables with data too.I know how to get elements from table.But lets imagine i fetch data from db and store it in uploadviewmodel and pass that model to view i know how to do this but i dont know how to present it in dropdown list in view.