# Issues converting types to new selectitemlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, casting, type-conversion

vs'12 asp.net C# MVC4 EF code first

**in the controller**

```
var usernames = Roles.GetUsersInRole("Admin");
var adminUsers = db.UserProfiles
                 .Where(x => !usernames.Contains(x.UserName)).ToList();

List<UserProfiles> myList = adminUsers.ToList();
IEnumerable<UserProfiles> myEnumerable = myList;

ViewBag.DDLRoles = myEnumerable;
```

**The error coming into the view states**

`The ViewData item that has the key 'DDLRoles' is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[[OG.Models.UserProfiles, OG, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.`

And i have been trying to convert this query to `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` like crazy, If anyone can help me convert this the right way i'd appreciate it alot.

Also if i did not make it clear, what I'm doing is taking a list of users from the linq query that are NOT of **"Admin"** Roles and I am trying to display them inside of a DropDrownList

EDIT: *the view*

`@model OG.Models.UserProfiles`

then later

`@Html.DropDownList("DDLRoles", (SelectList)ViewData["SelectedValue"])`

Comment: Can you post the code that references `ViewBag.DDLRoles` in your view?

Comment: Please post your View.

Comment: Check my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951524/mvc-and-entity-framework-select-list/17953161#17953161

Comment: So, your Model you pass to your View is of type UserProfiles? And, you only have on DropDownList in your View?

Comment: @ataravati Yeah thats right, passing the model ( cause i don't know how to convert it) and only 1 DDL in the View

Comment: What's the primary key of the UserProfiles class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your View should be like this:

```
@model OG.Models.UserProfiles

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserID, new SelectList(ViewBag.DDLRoles, "UserID", "UserName", Model.UserID))
```

And, in your Controller, you'll have:

```
var usernames = Roles.GetUsersInRole("Admin");
var adminUsers = db.UserProfiles
                 .Where(x => !usernames.Contains(x.UserName)).ToList();

ViewBag.DDLRoles = adminUsers;
```

This will submit the UserID of the selected user from the DropDownList to your Action. By the way, please choose more meaningful names for your Models. Your "UserProfiles" Model should be called "UserProfile" or "User", because it represents one User only, not a collection of Users.

Comment: error: `System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' does not contain a property with the name 'UserID'` - in the view

Comment: There's no SelectListItem here. Did you use my code or Jason's code? Please make sure the code in your Controller and in your View are same as the code in my answer.

Comment: And, make sure the UserProfiles class has a property (primary key) named UserID.

Comment: works wonderfully, how would i get this data out of the ddl from my `HTTPPost` controller?

Comment: Well, what you want to do is not very clear. Why do you have a View with only one DropDownList in it? Can you explain what this code is supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter needs to be an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, something like this:

```
@{
    List<UserProfiles> Users = ViewBag.DDLRoles;
}

@Html.DropDownList("Users", Users.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.UserName, Value = x.UserName }));
```

Comment: still receiving `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<OG.Models.UserProfiles>'` if its converted in controller or in view

Comment: this is my fault your code ran find aswell, as soon as i went to the right action.