# Creating a dropdown list for MVC ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-helper

I'm currently facing problems in creating drop down list. In my View, I need to have a label and a drop down list where label from tableA and dropdownlist from tableB. The value of dropdownlist will based on the value from tableA. Pleas take a look at the code below

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @foreach (var x in item.UserConfigDtls)
        {
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => x.ListOfValue)<br/>
        }
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.UserConfigHdrID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.UserConfigHdrID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.UserConfigHdrID })
    </td>

</tr>
}
```

From the above code, I can successfully display a name with the corresponding list of value. Now my problem is i want the individual set of values to become a drop down list instead of displaying them. May I know how can I do it as I'm very new to MVC ASP.NET.

Comment: Look at my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951524/mvc-and-entity-framework-select-list/17953161#17953161

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It will not be applicable for my case. It will be good if I can solve it at the view. I know that there is html.dropdownlist and html.dropdownlistfor however I've no idea how to utilize them.

Comment: @Jatin patil, Its working now. Do you have any idea on how to fix the width for the dropdownlist?

Comment: `@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => Model.typeToStoreValue, 
    Model.List, 
    new { style = "width: 250px;" }
)`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => x.ListOfValue, new SelectList(item.UserConfigDtls, "Id", "Name"), "Select")
```

Comment: in which field do you want to store the value you select from your combobox?

Answer (score 0):

In Controller Bind the Select List to your Model :

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        YourType model = new YourType ();
        model.List = GetSelectList();
        return View(model);
    }

    [NonAction]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSelectList()
    {
        var items = //Your List Object
        return items.Select(name => new SelectListItem() {
                    Text = name.prop,
                    Value = name.prop2
               });
    }
```

Then In View You can Bind List as Follows:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.typeToStoreValue,Model.List)
```