# making optimize in filling drop-down

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

i have two tables .
tbl-one (id,name-country) . tbl-two(id, name-city, id-tbl-one)
i have a drop-down-list . this items are like this:

```
       Australia,Au-city1
       Australia,Au-city2
       Australia,Au-city3
       Australia,Au-city4
        ...
       America,Am-city1
       America,Am-city2
       America,Am-city3
       ...

       England,En-city1
       England,En-city2
       England,En-city3
       ...
```

i use below code to fill my drop-down:

```
             <select id="CountryAndCity" class="span5">
                <option>--- select country/city ---</option>

                @foreach (var item in Project.Models.MyClass.getAllCitys())
                {
                    <option value="@item.id">

                        @item.city ,
                        @Project.Models.MyClass.getOnerecordCountryWithIDcity(int.Parse(item.id.ToString())).country

                    </option>
                }
            </select>
```

it works . but i wanna minimum refer to database . is it possible in another coding? or can i edit my code in better way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951524/mvc-and-entity-framework-select-list/17953161#17953161

Comment: Are you using the entity framework?

Comment: yes , entity framework